# How can I programatically get control of slick.js carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Normally I get control of carousels (*control you ask, means the state where I can use my arrow keys to slide them*) via clicking [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousels.

But I'm trying to do this with javascript code, to implement more flexible interface in my project.

Is this carousel control acquisition can be implemented programmatically? I have tried `$('#my-slick-carousel').focus()` but it didn't worked.

Any workarounds even not specific to the [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) are OK, as it seems like it's a problem of delegating `keypress` events to the carousel jquery objects.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correcty what you are trying to achieve: If you just want to call *Prev* and *Next* from a JS function you can do so by:

    $("#your-slider-id").slick('slickPrev');

Comment: @Sebastian You got the question wrong, What I want is acquiring control (keyboard-sliding enabled state) of the slick carousel with javascript, not sliding them with javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were so close with your original solution attempt.

Instead of `$('#my-slick-carousel').focus()`, you should use `$('#my-slick-carousel').find('.slick-list').focus()`, because the keyboard event handlers are registered on the `.slick-list` element, instead of the root carousel element.

Comment: I had to first add a `tabindex=0` attribute / value to the list before I could focus this. Final code looked more like this:

`$('.slick-list').attr('tabindex', 0).focus();`